# Bug in finding minimum spanning tree using Kruskal's algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, kruskals-algorithm

I write the code from adding vertex into a graph and update the weight of edge and then find the minimum spanning tree. I think that I have done it but there seems to be some error in it but I cannot find it out.The  system using Valgrind and indicate that "invalid write of size 4" and "invalid read of size 4 " in the call of MST, but I think it work fine.The whole error of Valgrind is https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_AhOdDkyZGNTBVHspyGtnSQoU1tYkm0nVA5UABmKljI/edit?usp=sharing

The following code is called by like

```
CreateNewGraph();
AddEdge(1, 2, 10);
AddEdge(2, 4, 10);
AddEdge(1, 3, 100);
AddEdge(3, 4, 10);
GetMST(mst_edges);
```

and the result will be (1,2) (2,4) (3,4).

and call

```
UpdateEdge(1, 3, 0.1);
GetMST(mst_edges);
```

and the result will be (1,2) (1,3) (2,4).

It is sent to a system to execute and it will be called like above but in a lot of time cycle above.

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

namespace HOMEWORK{
    class Edge{
        public:
            Edge(unsigned int, unsigned int, double);
            unsigned int u;
            unsigned int v;
            double w;
        friend bool operator<(const Edge& a, const Edge& b){
         return a.w < b.w;
        }
    };
    Edge::Edge(unsigned int source = 0, unsigned int destination = 0, double weight = 0.0){
        u = source;
        v = destination;
        w = weight;
    }

    vector<Edge> graph(0);
    vector<int> parent(0);

    int findset(int x){
        if(x != parent[x])parent[x] = findset(parent[x]);
        return parent[x];
    }

    void CreateNewGraph(){
        graph.clear();
        parent.clear();
    }

    void AddEdge(unsigned int u, unsigned int v, double w){
        graph.push_back(Edge(u,v,w));
    }

    void UpdateEdge(unsigned int u, unsigned int v, double w){
        for(int i = 0; i < graph.size(); i ++){
            if(graph[i].u == u && graph[i].v == v)graph[i] = Edge(u,v,w);
        }
    }

    void GetMST(vector<pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> >& mst_edges){
        mst_edges.clear();
        parent.clear();
        int e = graph.size();
        for(int i = 0; i <= e + 1; i ++)parent.push_back(i);
        stable_sort(graph.begin(), graph.end());
        for(int i = 0; i < e; i ++){
            //cout << graph[i].u << ":" << graph[i].v << ":" << graph[i].w << ":" << parent[i + 1] << endl;
            int pu = findset(graph[i].u);
            int pv = findset(graph[i].v);
            if(pu != pv){
                parent[pu] = parent[pv];
                mst_edges.push_back(make_pair(graph[i].u, graph[i].v));
            }
        }
    }

    void Init(){
    }

    void Cleanup(){
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest that you fire up your debugger. This is a critical tool for every aspiring programmer to learn.

Comment: In the Valgrind output, you have the file name and the line numbers of where the problem is. Look at that first. Or at least please indicate *where* in the source you provided that the problems are.

Comment: it says HOMEWORK::GetMST(std::vector<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> > >&) (code.cpp:29)the line isn't the code and the above code seems right.

Comment: Also you might have potential access beyond the limits of the vector. For example in `findset` you access `parent[x]` without checking that `x` is a valid index. Incidentally it also happens to be line 29 if the code showed is the full file of `code.cpp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is how you're setting up parent pointers.  Note that you've set up `parents` as

```
for(int i = 0; i <= e + 1; i ++) parent.push_back(i);
```

This creates one entry in the `parent` array for each edge in the graph, plus one extra one.  However, each *node* has a parent, not each *edge*, and the number of nodes in a graph can be bigger than the number of edges plus one.  For example, suppose you're given this set of edges:

```
1  2
3  4
5  6
```

This graph clearly has six nodes in it (numbered 1 ... 6), but your code would only make space for 4 entries in `parents`.

Try changing your code so that you set `parents` to be the proper size, probably by finding the maximum and minimum numbered node in the list of edges and sizing the array appropriately.  Alternatively, consider using a `std::unordered_map<int, int>`, which is more flexible if the vertex numbers don't contiguously begin at 0.

Hope this helps!